# PSExec can not find the file specified

Tags: vb.net, psexec

I've been using the remote tool PSEXEC for a while. Great tool and works great in command line. However I cannot get it to work on button.click in VB.NET

Commandline (works fine)

```
Psexec \\ComputerName -h -i -s \\FileServer\Share$\ .exe f2C:\psexeclog.txt -f1\\FileServer\Share$\setup.iss
```

Here's my VB.Net Code

```
Try
    Dim p As New Process()
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\path to\PsExec"
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\\ComputerName -h -i -s \\FileServer\Share$\ .exe f2C:\psexeclog.txt -f1\\FileServer\Share$\setup.iss"
    p.Start()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Could not compete action")
End Try
```

This connects to the computername fine! The error is when to runs the .exe remotely.

> **Error:** Psexec could not start \FileServer\Share$\ .exe on ComputerName The system cannot find the file specified.

The command line command above works great. Why doesn't the vb.net code ?

Comment: Try putting every parameter in a double quote in the `.Arguments`-string.

Comment: The SYSTEM account probably does not have access to `\\FileServer\Share$`.